# angular material missing packages

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I have upgrade my project to angular 13.2.1 this including @angular/material.
The problem is that I keep getting.

```
./src/app/material.module.ts:11:0-55 - Error: Module not found: Error: Package path ./Tabs is not exported from package F:\xxxxxx\Git\yyyyyy\node_modules\@angular\material (see exports field in F:\xxxxxx\Git\yyyyyy\node_modules\@angular\material\package.json)

./src/app/material.module.ts:12:0-57 - Error: Module not found: Error: Package path ./Table is not exported from package F:\xxxxxx\Git\yyyyyy\node_modules\@angular\material (see exports field in F:\xxxxxx\Git\yyyyyy\node_modules\@angular\material\package.json)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:0-61 - Error: Module not found: Error: Package path ./Stepper is not exported from package F:\xxxxxx\Git\yyyyyy\node_modules\@angular\material (see exports field in F:\xxxxxx\Git\yyyyyy\node_modules\@angular\material\package.json)

./src/app/material.module.ts:14:0-55 - Error: Module not found: Error: Package path ./Sort is not exported from package F:\xxxxxx\Git\yyyyyy\node_modules\@angular\material (see exports field in F:\xxxxxx\Git\yyyyyy\node_modules\@angular\material\package.json)
```

Below is my material.module.ts

```
import {A11yModule} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import {PortalModule} from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import {ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import {CdkStepperModule} from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {CdkTreeModule} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTreeModule} from '@angular/material/tree';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/Tabs';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/Table';
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/Stepper';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/Sort';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatBadgeModule} from '@angular/material/badge';
import {MatBottomSheetModule} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';


@NgModule({
  exports: [
    A11yModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    PortalModule,
    ScrollingModule,
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}


/**  Copyright 2019 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
 can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

Comment: Can you show the content of your `material.module.ts` ?

Comment: It is there. I have added it a long time ago.

Comment: tried to delete node_modules and reinstalling it ?

Comment: it does not help

Comment: Did you try using `@angular/material/tabs` instead of `@angular/material/Tabs`?